# Is every Genuino model and Arduino model compatible completely?

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide, arduino-yun, arduino-due

Just as the title; I want to order a Genuino model(non-USA product) and want to know if a Genuino model is compatible with an Arduino model.(Software-source, add-ons, etc)

Comment: @MehdiDehghani What exactly do you expect to be tried here?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are the same thing. Arduino cannot use the name 'Arduino' outside of the US, so they simply call them 'Genuino'.